# 500 internal server error in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

[image]I have a problem with Yii framework, everything was working locally jz fine but when I tried to move my app to another system some of the views are showing errors like 'undefined variables'.
anyone know about this issue.

I found some similar issues with yii but none of them provided a correct answer for me.

### EDIT

actually I have 2 dropdown boxes, 1st one is getting the value from the model, if we select 1 from 1st dropdown list it will filter the results and shows in the second dropdown list(ajax call), both dropdown boxes using different controller action

And in firezilla I am getting the 500 internal server error for the request and following image contains log as response.

Comment: You can't really call that an issue. It just means there are issues but it can be anything. What do your logs say?

Comment: Furthermore, if you get 'undefined variables' you **have** undefined variables and need to define them.

Comment: but it was working fine in my local system, I didnt make any changes. this is why i am confused

Comment: actually I have 2 dropdown boxes, 1st one is getting the value from the model, if we select 1 from 1st dropdown list it will filter the results and shows in the second dropdown list, both dropdown boxes using different controller action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors concerning undefined variables where probably always there, but not shown due to less strict values of the [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) configuration directives.

Undefined variables do not usually cause a 500 internal server error. Consult the log file of the web server for details on those errors.

Comment: Maybe that's rather something for the comments?

Comment: I have attached log file, please take a look at it

Comment: More details about the 500 internal server error can be found in the log file of the web server.

Comment: In firezilla its showing 500 internal server error for my request.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you are using PHP 5.2 on you local dev machine and other systems use 5.3. 
In 5.3 if there's some undefined variable ($result in your case) PHP will throw you a notice **by default**.

Few years ago, when I moved Yii project from 5.2 to 5.3 I got lots of these.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. My website with ajax works perfectly in the localhost. but when i uploaded it to the server, I realized the ajax request where not workin returning the 500 internal error. And when i click the url it says that undefined variable. 
Solution: Check the url of the ajax request:
before:

```
echo CHtml::textField('idsearch', '', array(
    'onKeyUp' => CHtml::ajax(
            array(
                'type' => 'POST',
                'dataType' => 'html',
                'data' => array(
                    'id' => 'js:idsearch.value'),
                'update' => '#dvfeeform',
                'url' => CController::createUrl('student/searchajax'),
    ))
));
```

after editing the url to:

```
'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('student/searchajax'),
```

it worked perfectly fine.
hope it may help someone someday

Answer (score 0):

I have passed an empty array $result from the controller to the view, Now its working fine.

But till now I couldn't figure it out why it worked perfectly in my local host and not in the other system.

Comment: ahh I guess a lot of wayward travelors wil stop by meantime

Comment: yeah, but it will be so grateful if someone can

Comment: @NikhilDinesh, have you read through what I linked under the words "error_reporting" and "display_errors" in my answer? Have you investigated whether this is the reason why you did not see these errors on your local system? If so, what was the result? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, I have tried error_reporting by setting E_ALL $~ E_NOTICE, then I got PHP notice changed to PHP warning.